# Problemas de divisão com BigDecimal

Tags: java

```java
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class BD {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(5);
        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(60);
        BigDecimal c = null;
        
        try {
            c = a.divide(b);
        } catch (Exception erro) {
            System.out.println("Utilizando o RoundingMode");
            c = a.divide(b, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        }
        System.out.println("c = " + c);// imprime ZERO (0)
        //resultado deveria ser = 0,0833333333
    }
}
```

Quando faz 5/60 resultara em 0,0833333... não tem fim por isso cai no catch ate ai blz,
eu queria saber como eu faço essa divisão utilizando o *BigDecimal* sem q o valor seja 0 (zero) e sim 0.08333?

Comment: Ajuste a escala dos números que vão ser operados. Exemplo: https://ideone.com/YnWswi

Answer (score 0):

Realize tudo de uma vez, adicionado as casas decimais que você deseja e o método de arredondamento:

```
c = a.divide(b, 5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```